# Coldfusion connection reset by peer (socket error # 10054)

Tags: sockets, coldfusion

All -

We have been receiving Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data (on chrome) when accessing few websites.Few other websites on the same server are working fine.
We have checked our database log and it looks fine there.

Any suggestions on why this could be happening?

Comment: I think this is a chrome issue and not a coldfusion issue. Have you tried with other browsers?

Comment: Yes, firefox too throws an error "The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.". It does not work in IE too

Comment: is it possible to access the website directly by IP?

Comment: also try a 3rd party service like http://doj.me to see what it reports

Comment: Thanks travis. Issue has been tracked to some irules